# Does every polynomial with coefficient in p-adic integers have a root

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

I guess, that this is a very basic question, but still I cannot find a source to answer it nor am I able to give a solution by myself.

If $ f \in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p}[x]$ is a non-constant polynomial with coefficient in the $p$-adic integers for some prime number $p$, does $f$ always have a zero in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p}$?

I already read that the question above should be equivalent to asking whether $f$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Also it should have to do something with the Newton polygon, which I am not quite familiar with.

I would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^2-p$ has no root. The first thing to do is to show that when $f \mod p$ has a root and $f'(a)\ne 0\bmod p$ then the gradient descent converges to the unique root $A\in \Bbb{Z}_p$ such that $A=a\bmod p$.

It is true that $f$ has a root iff it has a root in every $\Bbb{Z/p^kZ}$, this is because if $f$ has no root then in a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ $$f(x) = c\prod_{j=1}^d (x-\alpha_j)$$ so $$|f(n)|_p= |c|_p\prod_{j=1}^d |n-\alpha_j|_p \ge |c|_p A^p$$ where $A=\inf_{n\in \Bbb{Z},j} |n-\alpha_j|_p$ which is $> 0$ since otherwise some sequence of integers would converge to some $\alpha_j$ ie. $\alpha_j$ would be in $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Can you also say something about common roots in $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p})^2$ of two polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ that generate a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$? Does there always exist one for some prime $p$? Thank you so much!

Comment: (I was completely wrong about $\zeta_p$, please forget it) I added a proof that having a proof in every $Z/p^kZ$ is sufficient

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: On my question in the above comment: It is somehow related to my actual question, because taking $f,g$ as above, we can assume that $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible. Then $f$ will have a zero in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ for infinitely many primes $p$. If we take such a zero $\alpha_p$ for each such $p$, then is it true that the polynomial $g(\alpha_p,y)$ with coefficients in the $p$-adic integers must have a zero at least for some $p$? (It seems natural to me, because we now can choose from infinitely many primes $p$, and a thing as in your example can happen in at most finitely many.)